# Xubuntu showing up as Ubuntu in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, xubuntu

I decided before I commit 100% to a distro that I would dual boot Ubuntu and Xubuntu and see after some time which "feels" better to me. Well, after restarting the computer for the first time I saw this screen:

[image]

I was confused as I saw -two- options for Ubuntu. I know that Xubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu but why is it showing up as Ubuntu (and not Xubuntu) in GRUB?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @teratogen: If chaskes' answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. `os-prober` sees the core of the system, not the desktop environment; and this is what it uses to create the boot menu.

The first listing, given as just Ubuntu, is whichever install is controlling grub on /dev/sda.

I'm assuming you installed Ubuntu first, followed by Xubuntu. The menu listings will depend on how you installed the bootloader.

If you installed the bootloader to /dev/sda when installing Xubuntu, then the first `Ubuntu` listing at the top is Xubuntu and the 2nd `Ubntu 14.04 LTS` listing is Ubuntu.

If while installing Xubuntu, you installed the bootloader to its partion, say `/dev/sda3`, then ran `update-grub` in Ubuntu; then the first listing is Ubuntu and the 2nd listing is Xubuntu.